# (micro)python random module importError

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a random number between x and y int (micropython for esp), but

```
import random
```

gives the following error:

```
ImportError: no module named 'random'
```

I've seen some things online about this but no concrete solution. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because random module does not exist for micro python.

Please refer to the following link for help regarding your issue

https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2727

Comment: That explains. Thanks mate!